# How to upload pytest report to Gitlab Ci

Tags: gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

I have a repo of a Django app on Gitlab. The app is deployed to an Azure Linux Instance. I can't seem to get the pytest reports visible on the GitLab CI despite all the combinations I have tried. The problem lies around me not clearly knowing how GitLab gets files created by pytest running inside an ssh session.

Please note I have left out some unnecessary details below:
Here is my pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --junitxml=report.xml
```

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml script and artifacts section

```
script:
    - ssh eric@111.222.333.44 "cd /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal; /home/eric/.virtualenvs/eric-uat/bin/pytest"

artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - /builds/my-company/eric/eric-portal/report.xml
      - report.xml
      - ./report.xml
      - /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal/report.xml
      - eric-portal/report.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - /builds/my-company/eric/eric-portal/report.xml
        - report.xml
        - ./report.xml
        - /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal/report.xml
        - eric-portal/report.xml
```

Here is part of what is generated during the test stage

```
----- generated xml file: /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal/report.xml ------
======================== 1 passed, 2 warnings in 1.24s =========================
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /builds/my-company/eric/eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: report.xml: no matching files             
WARNING: ./report.xml: no matching files           
WARNING: /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /builds/my-company/eric/eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: report.xml: no matching files             
WARNING: ./report.xml: no matching files           
WARNING: /home/eric/www/uat/eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
WARNING: eric-portal/report.xml: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

`/builds/my-company/eric/eric-portal/report.xml` is what I get when I run `readlink -f report.xml` immediately after the pytest script

I would also love some advice on whether this is an efficient way of setting up CI for testing a Django app (I have 3 stages: **build, test,and deploy** and all happen in ssh session). I am currently running the tests on the server. Is there a way to run the tests on GitLab without SSHing into my server?

Comment: Configure and start the runner on `111.222.333.44` and invoke `pytest` without ssh'ing into the machine.

Comment: @hoefling Kindly give some guidance on how I can do that

Comment: I think I better understand now what you are doing - are you running the tests on the *deployed* application? That's definitely a no-go. In the CI, you should clone the Git repository with your source code, install the project dependencies and execute the tests. Never use the deployed app for executing unit tests on.

Comment: Of course, with your current setup, there's a workaround of copying the report file back into the runner env by using `scp eric@111.222.333.44:/remote/path/to/report.xml local/path/to/report.xml` and publish `local/path/to/report.xml` under `artifacts:reports`. But the way to go should be running unit tests on the separate clone of the repository, which Gitlab CI will do for you anyway.

Comment: Sadly that's what I am doing. Just came across this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04. Let me try it out and see how it works

Comment: This may be even too much to begin with - set the goal to execute the unit tests in the Gitlab CI first. For that, you don't need much as IIRC Gitlab offers CI runners for open source projects for free (and also there are probably less verbose tutorials for that available). Once you have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that runs the unit tests in the cloned repo and publishes the report, you can extend it step by step to add building docker images/deploying to Azure/whatever.

Comment: Yeah. This is the way to go. I found this useful https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Django.gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing all the ci in gitlab runners- build and test.
You can build an image using [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) inside the runner.
Then your tests would run directly on the runner, and the runner will have access to the output.
The deploy can also be done from the runner- assuming you uploaded your docker image to a registry, it is a matter of pulling and running the image in your cluster.

Comment: Yeah, I considered doing all the Ci in GitLab runners. I am however not using docker.